# How to replace a text with an JS icon?

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JS and created an app game in which a user guesses random day and random month. When the user gets both of them right, I want to replace the question mark with a heart icon from JS icons. Somehow it doesn't work.

I tried this code:

```
if (guessDay === secretDay && guessMonth === secretMonth) {
  document.getElementById("victory").innerHTML = "";
}
```

I also tried replacing the heart icon with a word: "Victory" but it didn't work either.

Full code below:

```js
let secretMonth = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
let secretDay = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 31) + 1;
console.log(secretMonth, secretDay);

document.querySelector(".btn-month").addEventListener("click", function () {
  const guessMonth = Number(document.querySelector(".guess-month").value);

  if (guessMonth === secretMonth) {
    document.querySelector(
      ".hint-month"
    ).textContent = `You got the month right.`;
    document.querySelector(".left").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  } else if (guessMonth >= secretMonth) {
    document.querySelector(".hint-month").textContent = `Go lower.`;
    document.querySelector(".left").style.backgroundColor = "#d9480f";
  } else {
    document.querySelector(".hint-month").textContent = `Go higher.`;
    document.querySelector(".left").style.backgroundColor = "#d9480f";
  }
});

document.querySelector(".btn-day").addEventListener("click", function () {
  const guessDay = Number(document.querySelector(".guess-day").value);

  if (guessDay === secretDay) {
    document.querySelector(".hint-day").textContent = `You got the day right.`;
    document.querySelector(".right").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  } else if (guessDay >= secretDay) {
    document.querySelector(".hint-day").textContent = `Go lower.`;
    document.querySelector(".right").style.backgroundColor = "#d9480f";
  } else {
    document.querySelector(".hint-day").textContent = `Go higher.`;
    document.querySelector(".right").style.backgroundColor = "#d9480f";
  }
});

document.querySelector(".btn-reset").addEventListener("click", function () {
  document.querySelector(".hint-day").textContent = "";
  document.querySelector(".hint-month").textContent = "";
  document.querySelector(".right").style.backgroundColor = "#d9480f";
  document.querySelector(".left").style.backgroundColor = "#d9480f";
  document.querySelector(".guess-month").value = "";
  document.querySelector(".guess-day").value = "";
});

if (guessDay === secretDay && guessMonth === secretMonth) {
  document.getElementById("victory").innerHTML = "victory";
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <header>
        <h1>Guess my birthday</h1>
        <div class="divider"><span id="victory">?</span></div>
      </header>
      <main>
        <section class="left">
          <div class="label-container">
            <p class="range">Between 1-12</p>
            <p class="label">month</p>
          </div>
          <input class="guess guess-month" type="number" min="0" max="12" />
          <button class="btn btn-month">Check</button>
          <p class="hint hint-month"></p>
        </section>
        <section class="right">
          <div class="label-container">
            <p class="range">Between 1-31</p>
            <p class="label">day</p>
          </div>

          <input class="guess guess-day" type="number" min="0" max="31" />
          <button class="btn btn-day">Check</button>
          <p class="hint hint-day"></p>
        </section>
        <button class="btn btn-reset">Reset</button>
      </main>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The logic is correct but the code is not running at the right moment in the right scope. The conditional check happens at the same time as registering event handlers.

```js
// register month click
// register day click
// register reset click

// too early to check the guess, no guesses have been made yet
if (guessDay === secretDay && guessMonth === secretMonth) {
  document.getElementById("victory").innerHTML = "victory";
}
```

In order to fix the problem, there are two steps.

1. Put the victory check in a helper function to call on both the day and month submit if the guess is right.
2. Keep track of the day and month guess in the parent scope to allow checking for victory after guessing either value.

```js
let secretMonth = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 12) + 1;
let secretDay = Math.trunc(Math.random() * 31) + 1;

// keep track of last day and month guess in parent scope
let guessMonth;
let guessDay;

    // in click event handler set outer scope variable (no const)
    guessMonth = Number(document.querySelector(".guess-month").value);
```

In terms of checking for victory it could be a helper function.

```js
function checkVictory() {
  if (guessDay === secretDay && guessMonth === secretMonth) {
    document.getElementById("victory").innerHTML = "victory";
  }
}

   // in click event handler
   if (guessDay === secretDay) {
     // update styles

     checkVictory();
   }
```

Comment: I added this to day button and month button: } else if (guessMonth === secretMonth && guessDay === secretDay) {
    checkVictory();
  }. I declared the new variables: let guessMonth;
let guessDay; But it still doesn't work. (Separately - the div change styles when the day is correct or the month) but the final message doesn't show.

Comment: The conditional logic is wrong, if you have a condition with else if that is more specific than a previous if statement it will never hit that code.

Comment: So should I put the "check victory" condition as the first one and then put condition (correct day) as "if else". I didn't know the order was important. It was supposed to be a game like. First you try to get the day right, then the month. IF you got both of them right I wanted to "checkVictory()" to run?

Comment: Try it out! In JavaScript "if else" means if the previous condition is false, then check this next condition as a backup.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the conditions for the month. Because after I checked the victory for the day and styles were applied, the same style was supposed to be applied to the month div but only the victory for both was applied. Therefore the game must be done in the predifined order. Guess the day first, then guess the month and the month styling must be applied together with the victory styling. (I removed the victory for the month and applied victory for the game instead.